# Image export in eps not visible in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a quite complex figure which I want to export as an EPS. This figure contain an image created with `imagesc`. When I save it as a PNG file everything looks fine; however, when exported as an EPS, everything except the image is exported properly.

Here is the correct output: (using .png)

[image: Correct Output in png]

And the .eps one:

[image: Wrong Output]

[Here](https://github.com/Rafnuss/BSGS/raw/master/result/0-Illutstration/Illustration_Neighbour-general_2015-11-05_15-42-04.fig) is the .fig file.

I tried the `export_fig` FEX using the command `export_fig test.eps` and it also gave me the [same result](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rafnuss/BSGS/master/test.eps)

I am using Matlab 2015b on Ubuntu.

Comment: I can replicate this on OS X using R2015b. I've had this sort of bug before. You may need to save/export as a PDF instead (possibly using Export Setup... under the figure's File menu as well).

Comment: use FEX `export_fig`

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I tried it... doesn't work for me. Have you try ?

Comment: @horchler, yes, this could be a plan B option, but I'll like to make it with .eps

Comment: How did you tried and failed? "I tried it... doesn't work for me" gives zero information.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, sorry, I mean, it give me the same figure that I put on the post above (without the imagesc plot) [link to  the eps file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rafnuss/BSGS/master/test.eps). I added this info on the post also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is a late reply to this question but I figured that I would provide an explanation for what is happening just in case anyone had this issue in the future.

The basic issue here is that EPS files do not natively support transparency (this is why `export_fig` didn't yield a different result). MATLAB is aware of this so when you try to print a figure using transparency it tries to do it's best to recreate the image that you have on your screen. Unfortunately, it also fails.

So let's take a very simple example. We are going to create a red `surf` and make it so that each element has a different `Alpha` value.

```
% Surface with random transparency between 0 (transparent) and 1 (opaque)
surf(zeros(10), 'FaceColor', 'r', 'AlphaData', rand(10), 'FaceAlpha', 'flat');
```

Now let's save a PNG and EPS version and check them out.

[image]
[image]

Not too bad, right? It looks like transparency was preserved between the PNG and EPS version. This is mostly true, except where we defined the surface to be *completely* transparent. In those regions, MATLAB actually substituted *solid* red in for those regions. More simply, in regions that are completely white in the PNG, they are completely red in the EPS.

To demonstrate this further, let's create a surface where the `AlphaData` is either `0` (completely transparent) or `0.1` (mostly transparent).

```
surf(zeros(10), 'FaceColor', 'r', 'AlphaData', eye(10)/10, 'FaceAlpha', 'flat');
```

[image]
[image]

Ok so now we can see that if we define something to be fully transparent, MATLAB doesn't even try to make something transparent. It does quite the opposite. On the other hand, the semi-transparent regions *seem* to be semi-transparent still. Are they actually transparent?

To determine if there is actually transparency here, let's go back to the first example for a second. Let's try changing the `axes` color to black so we can see if it's actually transparent.

```
set(gca, 'Color', 'k')
```

And the results when saved as a PNG and EPS

[image]
[image]

Well that's interesting...so what exactly is going on here. As I said earlier, MATLAB knows that an EPS is incapable of containing transparency information. It also knows that your figure contains transparency and it wants to include this information somehow. The way that it does this, is that it dithers your color with the *expected* background color (white) to create the *appearance* of transparency. Unfortunately, if you have anything *under* your transparent object that *isn't* white, you're not going to see it because at the end of the day, the more transparent regions are simply more white and *not actually more transparent*.

For variably transparent data like this, that's quite the problem and really the only workarounds are to save it in a format that *does* support transparency, or you can open the resulting EPS file in a EPS editor, alter the transparency of the plot objects there, and then re-export as a different format.

If, on the other hand, you don't have a plot object that has *variable* transparency, but rather one that has either opaque *or* transparent regions, there is a workaround.

What you can actually do is set the `FaceColor` of the transparent faces to `NaN`. This will cause that particular face to not even render and MATLAB will just ignore that face when printing to a file.

```
% Make everything but the diagonal be NaN (transparent)
cdata = ones(10);
cdata(~eye(10)) = NaN;

% Create a surface with no transparency and just CData with NaN values
surf(zeros(10), 'FaceColor', 'flat', 'CData', cdata);

% Change axes color to check transparency
set(gca, 'Color', 'k')
```

[image]
[image]

Now both the PNG and EPS are able to successfully show the colored `axes` underneath which means that everything off of the diagonal is functionally transparent in *both* the PNG and EPS. This works whether it's just an `axes` underneath or whether there are other plot objects as well.

So now, going back to the question you posted. Unfortunately the links to your images are no longer valid, but if you open the EPS file that was created, you will likely see that the image *is* underneath of the yellow/green surface, it's just that the surface used transparency and MATLAB forced the transparent regions to not be transparent, and dithered with white instead. This solid surface then covers up the image underneath when you view the resulting EPS file making it seem as if it vanished. If you change the transparent surface elements to have a `CData` value of `NaN`, you'll then be able to see the image through the surface at these locations.